# Does xapian supports fuzzy search?

Tags: fuzzy-search, inverted-index, xapian

So lucene supports fuzzy search based on edit distance algorithms, but i am wondering does xapian also support this feature? So a documents which includes term 'apple' will also be returned with the query='applo' which is a TYPO.

From what i known there's no query operator support this feature in xapian.